# shell script fails when calling another script with space-seperated parameters

Tags: shell

We've a script (script 1) that calls another script (script 2), which it expects to be passed in enclosed in quotes.

Complications ensue as script2 also takes a number of parameters, some of which are space-seperated strings and another is a sql script.

This causes script1 to fail.

Running script2 in isolation works as expected.
Script1 works when script2's arguments don't have any space seperated strings.

Behold:

```
<script1> "<script2 -s "ExchangeRates" <sqlscript.sql>"
```

works as expected.

However:

```
<script1> "<script2 -s "Exchange Rates" <sqlscript.sql>"
```

fails with:

SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "Rates" @/h..." - rest of line ignored.

i.e. it treats "Exchange" and "Rates" as two seperate strings.

So, I tried escaping the spaces:

```
<script1> "<script2 -s \"Exchange Rates\" <sqlscript.sql>"
```

But get exactly the same problem. I can imagine the solution to this is probably staring me in the face and amazingly simple, but I can't see it.

Any suggestions gratefully recieved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the space. Or to use two different kind of quotes.

Comment: I've already tried escaping the spaces (see example above). Not sure what you mean by different kind of quotes - please explain.

Comment: Ehm... no you didn't do `Exchange\ Rates` in any example above. By quotes I ment `'<script2 -s "Exchange Rates" <sqlscript.sql>'`.

Answer (score 0):

Script 1 should be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
"$@"  ## Expands multiple arguments properly regardless of spaces.
```

And to run it you should pass arguments properly:

```
script1 script2 -s 'Exchange Rates' sqlscript.sql
```

Inside `script1` the command would still be called like

```
script2 -s 'Exchange Rates' sqlscript.sql
```